# setting up an image is returning me null as input when it should be an image

Tags: java, image, bufferedimage, javax.imageio, illegalargumentexception

I'm having this print out in my console when it crashes:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at java.desktop/javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(ImageIO.java:1402)
    at com.cRS.crRS.graphics.Texture.loadBitmap(Texture.java:14)
    at com.cRS.crRS.graphics.Texture.<clinit>(Texture.java:9)
    at com.cRS.crRS.graphics.Render3D.floor(Render3D.java:75)
    at com.cRS.crRS.graphics.Screen.render(Screen.java:27)
    at com.cRS.crRS.Display.render(Display.java:185)
    at com.cRS.crRS.Display.run(Display.java:144)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
```

I don't understand why this code is crashing and not running.

I have added /res/ as a java build path. /res/ is alongside /src/ is the file directory.

```
/res/textures/floor.png
```

```
package com.cRS.crRS.graphics;

import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;

import javax.imageio.ImageIO;

public class Texture {
    public static Render floor = loadBitmap("/textures/floor.png");
    
    public static Render loadBitmap(String fileName) {
        try {
            BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(Texture.class.getResource(fileName));
            int width = image.getWidth();
            int height = image.getHeight();
            Render result = new Render(width, height);
            image.getRGB(0, 0, width, height, result.pixels, 0, width);
            return result;              
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("CRASH!");
            e.printStackTrace();
            throw new RuntimeException(e);      
        }
    } 
}
```

The program crashes when I use this line in a different class

```
pixels[x + y * width] = Texture.floor.pixels[(xPix & 7) + (yPix & 7) * 8];
```

To avoid crashing I don't use Texture.java at all but I want to.

Comment: *"I have added /res/ as a java build path."* -- But have you added /res to your Java runtime *class path*? That is what matters here.

Comment: @HaraldK You indirectly solved my problem. I went to recheck everything and I noticed my res folder was only imported in my libraries tab within the properties of my project. To add the folder as a source folder I had to first delete that and re-add the folder in the source tab only. Thanks so much, If you knew how long I've been coding this program for without importing images it would make you laugh haha

Answer (score 0):

"I have added /res/ as a java build path." -- But have you added /res to your Java runtime class path? That is what matters here.

– Harald K 3 hours ago

@HaraldK You indirectly solved my problem. I went to recheck everything and I noticed my res folder was only imported in my libraries tab within the properties of my project. To add the folder as a source folder I had to first delete that and re-add the folder in the source tab only. Thanks so much, If you knew how long I've been coding this program for without importing images it would make you laugh haha

– Anthony Mercadante
1 min ago

Comment: I suggest you to don't copy/paste but format content